# Correct way for one hot encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am a bit confused by what's online RE *one hot encoding*. I'm using the `get_dummies` method but what is not clear to me is if I apply one hot encoding BEFORE or after `train_test_split`. e.g. is this correct? It is a popular method but does this not lead to data leakage?

```
features = pd.get_dummies(features, columns=['country'], dummy_na=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, y, random_state=0)
```

e.g. in my case train contains all countries but test set contains all but Germany, but using the above way will keep Germany one hot encoded with a series of 0s and 1s in my TEST SET and therefore not just a series of 0s because it's absent. This seems wrong to me.

Comment: Note that [DataScienceSE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this kind of non-programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: always split first. Use only the training set for determining any aspect of feature representation.**

Any encoding should be calculated on the training set only in order to avoid data leakage. Then the same encoding is just applied to the test set.

Of course it's possible that a particular value doesn't appear in the training set but appears in the test set. There are different ways to deal with this, depending on the situation:

- Just ignore the unknown value in the test set, or replace it with a missing value.
- Remove any rare value (e.g. frequency lower than N) from the start and replace with a special category 'unknown'. Apply the same principle on the test set.

Additionally, note that rare values introduce a risk of overfitting if present in the training set. If not present in the training set, the value is useless since the model doesn't know it. That's why it's almost always a good idea to remove them from the start.

Comment: Keeping with the above since OHE is a fixed transformation I think it can be applied before the split

Comment: @mathella yes technically it can, but it's a logical mistake because at least in theory it should be possible to apply the model to any new instance, and it won't be possible to re-encode if the new instances contains an unknown value. That's why a good ML design would anticipate this case: encoding using only the training set is a good discipline since it forces you to address the issue and treat the test set as real fresh instances.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you have a lot of little categories. This is nit informative category and you can try to union them in one category in training. Lets call this category as C0. So, you take inference (test). On inference you get new category. You can add undefined category to C0 category and do predict.

Of course, you need to test this case on cross-validation.

Don't forget, that data is changed in time in real world. You need to find of source arrive new category, I think.

If you says about invented task, for example, [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) -problem, than good idea takes experiment with this case on cross-validation and maybe leader board. After that, you can understand what the best way to do.

In kaggle sometimes in test there are large category in test. It lays unreasnoable large category to C0. You need to research your problem. Probably, this is key to solve.